# I have problem solving a specific matrix, even though my method has worked countless of times over in the past!

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

The matrix in question is A: \begin{bmatrix}6&-1&-3\\6&-1&-3\\2&-5&5\end{bmatrix}
and so I get a system of equations from AX=0

6x - y - 3z = 0

6x - y - 3z = 0

2x - 5y + 5z = 0

which I then apply Gauss elimination to:

14y - 18z = 0 (added 3rd equation multiplied by -3)

2x - 5y + 5z = 0

Now it seems I cannot solve it any further and so I put z = t and y = 2t, which gives me x = 5t/2. However, this does not seem to be correct! What am I doing wrong? Can it in fact be solved further?

Comment: Why did you put $y=-2t?$ That doesn't satisfy $7y-9z=0.$

Comment: That is the best one can solve. This is because $Ax = 0$ does not have unique solutions. As you can see the first two rows are the same implying there are only two equations with three variables. Thus the solution will be a line which is exactly what you get.

Comment: @SahibaArora I fixed it, it is supposed to be 2t!

Comment: @ancientmathematician Indeed, but that was an error when  wrote it here on the website :( I wrote it correct when I calculated it!

Comment: @Carl, that doesn't satisfy $7y-9z=0$ either.

Comment: From $z=t$ and $14y-18z=0$ you can get $y$; then from $2x-5y+5z$ you can get $x$.

Comment: @SahibaArora Thank you so much, you made me realise my mistake is incredibly silly, which is a relief for me! It has been a long day!

Comment: When there are just two equations in three variables you can write down the solution at sight: in this case anything parallel to $(6,-1,-3)\times (2,-5,5)=4 (5,9,-7)$

Answer (score 1):

You made a minor error by taking $y=2t.$ Since $7y=9z.$ Therefore $$2x=5(y-z)=5\left(\frac{9}{7}-1\right)z=\frac{10}{7}z,$$ i.e. $x=\frac{5}{7}z.$ Thus the solution is  $$\left\{\begin{bmatrix}5\\9\\7\end{bmatrix}t:t\in \mathbb{R}\right\}$$